# Deadlock within threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

So I am have a deadlock within my system and I, for the life of me, cannot figure out where it is.

Essentially within my system I have an array of 12 elements and 12 locks which correspond to each element. I then have 2 threads that create a function that performs calculations on an array. But each thread performs two element changes within the array at a time.

With just each thread looking at one element, there are no deadlocks but with each thread looking at two elements, there is a rare chance of a deadlock.

This is my code:

```
Thread() {

           - some other code that doesnt effect the threads -

           // randomly pick a lane between 0 - 15
           randLane1 = rand() % 16;
           randLane2 = rand() % 16;

           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);

           // if Rouge picked a lane that has already been fired at, look for a free lane
           while(Gallery->Get(randLane1) != white) {
              pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
              randLane1 = rand() % 16;
              pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
           }
           while(Gallery->Get(randLane2) != white || randLane2 == randLane1) {
              pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);
              randLane2 = rand() % 16;
              pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);
           }

           // set the lane's colour
           Gallery->Set(randLane1, PlayerColor);
           Gallery->Set(randLane2, PlayerColor);
           // set the thread to wait X amount of time to simulate a shot        
           usleep(1000000/rate);

           // upon lock for other threads
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);


}
```

If anyone is able to pinpoint where the deadlocking is occurring, that would be most helpful. If you need me to clarify the system some more, please ask.

Comment: this is not a proper way of handling threads, almost sure the deadlock is when randlane1 == randlane2

Comment: Debug step-by-step and check where deadlock occurs.

Comment: I don't get the masochistic people who still using pthreads/winapi over c++11. we're getting to 2016 very soon. seriously, move on.

Comment: @DanielSanchez I see what you mean, when I try to get a random lane for randLane2, if it happens to be equal to randLane1 then I will deadlock.

Comment: @DavidHaim Unfortunately I have to abide by the professors rules

Comment: @DanielSanchez Do you have any suggestions on how to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: Nope, I dont really know why are you handling 2 threads inside a single thread call... :/

Comment: The professors wants us to use fine grain locks and for each thread, it is supposed to perform two array element modifications at a time.

Comment: @QQCompi you are not aproaching the problem properly, make a function that shoul be runned in the 2 threads, they both have to do the same and you just have to handle the acces to the resources with mutexes

Comment: The "ordered algorithm" (that is in a couple of the answers below) is obviously what the professor is looking for in this assignment.  There is more than one way to solve this problem.  Here is a paper that compares the different algorithms by performance:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html

Answer (score 1):

in this part of your code:

```
while(Gallery->Get(randLane2) != white || randLane2 == randLane1) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);
    randLane2 = rand() % 16;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);
}
```

when randLand2 == randlane1;

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);
```

will never succeed since that mutex is already locked. To avoid this problem; you might consider doing something like:

```
int lockAcquired = 0;
while(!lockAcquired && Gallery->Get(randLane2) != white || randLane2 == randLane1) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);
    randLane2 = rand() % 16;
    if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]))
        lockAcquired = 1;
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't the while loop prevent that? Or is it that when I am within the loop and I run `randLane2 = rand() % 16`, if I happen to get the same value as randLane1, it will automatically try to lock it when it has already been taken by randLane1?

Comment: the latter yes: your code blocks just after the `rand % 16` line; trying to acquire the same mutex lock that was already locked in the loop above...

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to combat this deadlock issue?

Comment: you might consider using pthread_mutex_trylock and check whether it succeeded or not

Comment: Unfortunately in this assignment we are forced not to use a trylock() - which by the way makes no sense - but I can see your idea. Your code does work for my system so I will borrow what youve shown me and try to incorporate a method that doesnt involve a trylock(). Thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome. If your problem is solved now, you can mark that by accepting an answer; this makes it more clear for anyone passing by...

Answer (score 0):

Chris Maes has already addressed part of the problem - the issue with `randlane1 == randlane2` - but even with that addressed, your program can still deadlock.

The other, more subtle, issue is to do with the order you acquire the locks.

Suppose thread A decides it will acquire locks 4 & 5, and at the same time thread B decides it will acquire locks 5 & 4. Thread A will first obtain lock 4, and thread B will first obtain lock 5.

At this point, thread A will try to obtain lock 5 (which will block because thread B has it), and thread B will try to obtain lock 4 (which will block because thread A has it). Now neither thread can ever make any progress.

The solution to this is that you must always obtain locks in the same order, in all threads. That means you must define an order for the locks (for this example, numerical order would make sense), and never try to obtain a lock while holding another lock that comes later in the order.

In this example, you could fix the issue by swapping `randlane1` and `randlane2` if it turns out that `randlane1` is bigger - that will ensure that, in most cases, the locks are obtained in increasing order. Of course you'll also have to add more logic to cope with the case where `randlane1 == randlane2`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you aquire locks is ripe for deadlock.

Two thread senario

```
 Thread1                            Thread2
 =================                  =================
 lock1 = 1;                        
 lock2 = 2;

                                    lock1 = 2;
                                    lock2 = 1;
 mutex_lock(&array[lock1]);
                                    mutex_lock(&array[lock1]);
 mutex_lock(&array[lock2]);
                                    mutex_lock(&array[lock2]);
```

Here you are deadlocked.
Thread 1 is waiting for lock2 (and holding lock1).
Thread 2 is waiting for lock1 (and holding lock2).

The way to hold multiple locks is that they must be acquired in order. If you release and try and acquire a new lock you must again make sure that the locks are still acquired in order.

So if you were holding lock 4 and lock 5. Then you select that 5 is already being used and you randomly select lock 1 to replace it. Then you must release 4 and 5 and acquire locks 1 and 4 in that order.